# Sending Successful FTP File Upload Message with Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

**How do I trigger a message to be sent to a JdbcOutboundGateway only on a successful FTP file transfer?**

I have the below IntegrationFlow.  It is uploading the files just fine to the FTP server as desired.  However, I then need to write to a DB that the file has been successfully uploaded, or update a record if it fails on the FTP upload.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to initiate the DB update on file transfer success.  Anywhere I try to continue the flow, it just throws an exception stating that it is "one-way".

- ftpProps contains all the config values for the various FTP setups
- outboundMessages is the channel that messages are placed into that need to be sent via FTP
- ftpSessionFactoryFactory builds out all the various FtpSessionFactory objects from the values in the config file that the router will then determine which one to send the message to through inspecting a header value

The flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fromOutboundChannelToFtp(OutboundConfigurationProperties ftpProps,
                                                @Qualifier(OUTBOUND_CHANNEL) MessageChannel outboundMessages,
                                                @Qualifier(FTP_SESSION_FACTORY_FACTORY) FtpSessionFactoryFactory ftpSessionFactoryFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(outboundMessages)
            .route(RECEIVER_HEADER_SPEL, mapping -> {
                for (String receiverId : ftpProps.getFtp().keySet()) {
                    mapping.subFlowMapping(receiverId, sf -> {
                        sf.handleWithAdapter(adapter ->
                            adapter.ftp(ftpSessionFactoryFactory.getFactory(receiverId))
                            .fileNameExpression(FILENAME_HEADER_SPEL)
                            .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(ftpProps.getValue(receiverId, FtpProp.DIRECTORY))
                        );
                    });
                }
            })
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `outboundMessages` a publish/subscribe channel and subscribe a second flow to it with a JDBC adapter. Set the `order` property on the router and jdbc adapter consumers to ensure they are invoked in the right sequence.

By default, the second consumer won't be invoked if the first one fails.

Use an error channel on the flow entry point (upstream of the channel) to handle failures.

Alternatively, add an `ExpressionEvaluatingMessageHandlerAdvice` to the ftp adapters and add the JDBC adapter flow on the `success` channel and a different update flow on the `failure` channel.

Comment: Are there any non-xml examples out there to reference?  I'm having trouble finding how to do what you are suggesting with the order property.  The same with the expression advice with being unable to find any non-xml examples to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: I issued a [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/2021) yesterday with some improvements (and documentation for configuration with the DSL). Until that is merged (and released), you'll have to use distinct `channel()` beans rather than channel names. The order goes on the consumer (like the advice).

Comment: Great, thank you!  I was able to figure out how to configure it by looking at [lines 408 - 430](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/3301da4157123264df1e0c7db2d4b3095edd7193#diff-bdb762ced0d512ecaa75eed504d7c64aR394) and passing in the channel (instead of the newly added name method).